# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

Can't start Spring application even though all required dependencies are installed

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.15.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Report:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1082)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> Root Cause

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
> org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader$1.initialize(ConfigLoader.java:41)
> org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader$1.initialize(ConfigLoader.java:38)
> org.hibernate.internal.util.ValueHolder.getValue(ValueHolder.java:55)
> org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:244)
> org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:296)
> org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:281)
> Konstantin.Game.MVC.config.HibernateUtilConfig.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtilConfig.java:16)
> Konstantin.Game.MVC.DAO.GameDAO.findAll(GameDAO.java:43)
> Konstantin.Game.MVC.controllers.GameController.index(GameController.java:27)
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)

I have already tried variations from a similar question, namely adding the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But didn't help

What could help me?

UPD:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y78Ir.jpg

Comment: Your jaxb-runtime version is for Jakarta 9+, and uses the `jakarta` package namespace instead of the `javax` package namespace. You need to use a jaxb-runtime version of 2.3.x (e.g. 2.3.6).

Comment: Also, given you seem to be using Spring Boot, you should use the Spring Boot BOM to manage the versions of your dependencies, instead of you manually specifying each and every dependency version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding jaxb missing add these

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
    
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are planning to use Hibernate you will be needing javax packages as well they are from this dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also if you are using JDK11 or higher, it will require Hibernate to not be under version 5.4, but if you are using JDK8, it will work with any version of Hibernate.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help, I will supplement the question with a screenshot of the error that I receive((

Comment: This is the solution for your exception, you might be getting something else now, but I assume that is realted due to the fact that you are using Hibernate 6 and Hibernate Validator 7, which renamed their packages from JAVAX to JAKARTA,. At the moment Spring 5 does not work with JAKARATA packages, Spring 6 will tho. It is very bad practice to use the latest versions of everything that you can get your hands on.

Comment: anyway it did not help(
The error is still the same even after adding all your dependencies

Comment: You need to nuke your .m2 folder from your system and run your maven updates with mvn clean install command.

Comment: See? The picture is saying "jakarta" Please put your hibernate in order with correct versions and run mvn clean install.

Comment: Okay, I'l try now!

Comment: If you are using JDK11 or higher, it will require Hibernate to not be under version of 5.4